# AWS: identifying Access keys usage origin

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-iam

In the process of trying to achieve a [Well Architected Framework](https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/well-architected/), one of the relevant issues to remediate in the [Security pillar](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/architecture/AWS-Security-Pillar.pdf) is the one related to the following question: "How are you managing keys?"

We've managed to delete several unused keys, and switched to role based EC2 instances for other access key replacements, but we still have 3 keys for which we haven't been able to identify where they are being used from as the "Last Usage" section only shows a generic phrase such as "2018-05-08 01:04 ADT with ec2 in us-west-1", but there's now way to achieve deeper insight as from where in EC2 are requests coming from.

Our support provider has long ago stated that [CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/) might help, but they haven't provided further feedback on how to use it and/or configure CloudTrail to get more info on access keys' usage details.

Is it actually possible to discover from where this "orphaned" keys are being used from? I'm aware that making them inactive might help, as something would stop working, but I'm worried that I might not have the proper alarms to detect what went wrong, so I'm not particularly fond of this approach.

**Edit:**

Sample from CloudTrail data in [CloudWatchLogs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html) (sensitive data ofuscated):

```
{
    "eventVersion": "1.05",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "IAMUser",
        "principalId": "AIDAJOJXJKHCAFHDDAOR2",
        "arn": "arn:aws:iam::00000000000:user/myUser",
        "accountId": "078472214496",
        "accessKeyId": "AKIAIHS2WHR5REZYJ52Q",
        "userName": "myUser"
    },
    "eventTime": "2018-04-24T17:05:15Z",
    "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "DescribeSecurityGroups",
    "awsRegion": "eu-central-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "34.204.73.91",
    "userAgent": "Ruby",
    "requestParameters": {
        "securityGroupSet": {},
        "securityGroupIdSet": {},
        "filterSet": {}
    },
    "responseElements": null,
    "requestID": "42d48dd9-7eda-4631-bff5-47c81233a782",
    "eventID": "805eb3fb-d5bb-4fa7-804d-2a9cd920c0c0",
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "recipientAccountId": "00000000000"
}
```

Things about that event:

- Region is eu-central-1 and source ec2.amazonaws.com, but have no EC2 resources in that region, seems like something (Ruby based) is querying for existing resources (SecGroups, VPC, volumes...almost everything).
- Source IP: 34.204.73.91, not beloning to us

**Edit 2**:

Found in IAM I found out this about the last usage:

```
2018-05-08 14:33 ADT with cloudwatch in us-west-1a
```

But there are no CloudWatch related events in the CloudTrail CloudWatchLogs. Are there events not logged via CloudTrail?

Comment: CloudTrail is definitely the right approach. See the sample payload and instructions in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html - it'll give you the source IP, the API call made, etc.

Comment: @ceejayoz found out some info in CloudTrail, but I can't figure out where the request is actually coming from

Comment: Look at `eventName`, `sourceIPAddress`, `requestParameters`, etc. to get an idea of what it's doing. If you don't recognize the source as one of your servers or staff, I'd block.

Comment: @ceejayoz I would block it but it seems that there are still some CloudWatch events using this key, these are actually some of OUR metrics, but I haven't been able to identify their origin yet. That's why I added Edit #2 in the question above

Comment: OK, so you're going to want to see if you have an EC2 instance with a public IP of `34.204.73.91`, doing something related to security groups via a Ruby script. I see `eu-central-1` but I'm not sure if that's the bucket or where the API call is coming from.

Comment: If you don't have any EC2 instances matching that IP, it's time to start asking a) if you're running in multiple AWS accounts or b) if you're compromised somehow.